# Cannot populate dropdownlist in ASP.NET MVC 5 from Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, view, dropdown, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm trying to populate a dropdown list in ASP.NET MVC 5, but with no success.

Controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PartialRegistrationRoles()
{
        using (DBModels db = new DBModels())
        {
            List<Role> allRoles = db.Roles.ToList();
            var roles = new SelectList(db.Roles.ToList(),"RoleName");
            ViewData["DBRoles"] = roles.Items;
        }

        return View();
}
```

Partial view:

```
@using System.Collections
@using WorkFinder.Models
@model WorkFinder.Models.Role


<div class="form-group">
    @Html.DropDownList("Roles", new SelectList((IEnumerable) 
    ViewData["DBRoles"]),"Roleid","RoleName")
   </div>
```

Actual dropdown:

[The drop down is just retrieving some SYSTEM.DATA.ENTITY...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqQsx.png)

Error when browsing the main view, however, the dropdown shows in partial view:

[Error in main view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1msvM.png)

Can anyone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, take a look at the overload methods for [DropDownList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) and [SelectList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlist.-ctor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_SelectList__ctor_System_Collections_IEnumerable_).  Most likely you misplaced a bracket and intended to do something like:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Roles", new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["DBRoles"],"Roleid","RoleName"))
```

In terms of calling this as a partial view, please show the relevant code (the main view) and I will update the answer.